# Singly linked list following a weird display pattern

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

Following code works perfectly if I make 1 node and display. However, if I insert 2 or more nodes then only the last node entered is displayed and the ones that were already in linked list. E.g if I have linked List of 3 1 2 4 and I enter 2 1 3 consecutively and call the display function then output = 3 1 2 4 3.

```
    struct node
{
    char info;
    node* link;
}*f,*nn,*p,*c;//variables to make new node, head and control previous and current

void create(char inf)
{

    if(f=='\0')
    {
        nn=new node[sizeof(struct node)];
        nn->info=inf;
        nn->link='\0';
        f=c=p=nn;
    }
    else
    {

        nn=new node[sizeof(struct node)];
        nn->info=inf;
        p->link=nn;
        c=nn;
        c->link='\0';
    }
}

void display()
{

    c=p=f;
    while(c!='\0')
    {
        cout<<c->info<<" ";
        p=c;
        c=c->link;
    }
    cout<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    while(3)
    {
        int sw=0;
        cout<<"Enter \n1. to create list \n2. to display list"<<endl;
        cin>>sw;
        switch(sw)
        {
            case 1:{
            char info;
            cout<<"Enter info!"<<endl;
            cin>>info;
            create(info);
            break;
            }
            case 2:display();
            break;
            default:
            cout<<"Wrong entry, try again!"<<endl;
        }
    }


}
```

Pardon if something is so obvious since i have tried my best to find the solution.

Comment: Give your variables names that make sense, and you'll see where you made your mistake. `f` and `c` and `p` and `nn` are not what you want.

Comment: `c->link='\0'` is not a good idea. Better use `c->link = 0` or or `c->link = NULL`. c->link is a pointer and `'\0'` is a character in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems that I see:

1. `f`, `nn`, `p`, and `c` are not initialized.

   Change the lines to:

   ```
   struct node
   {
       char info;
       node* link;
   };

   node *f = NULL;
   node* nn = NULL;
   node* p = NULL;
   node* c = NULL;
   ```
2. Change the line

   ```
   if(f=='\0')
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (f == NULL)
   ```

   This is a style change but more readable. Use `'\0'` only for comparing characters. Use `NULL` for comparing pointers.
3. The following line does not seem right.

   ```
   nn=new node[sizeof(struct node)];
   ```

   It allocates an array of object containing `sizeof(struct node)` items and returns a pointer to that array. You just need one object. Change the line to:

   ```
   nn=new node;
   ```

   There are two such lines, one in each of the blocks under `if (f=='\0')`.
4. You are not making the links correctly under the `else` block.

   ```
   nn=new node[sizeof(struct node)];
   nn->info=inf;
   p->link=nn;  // This is good only for the second item.
                // When you add the third item, the second item becomes an orphan.
                // When you add the fourth item, the third item becomes an orphan.

   c=nn;
   c->link='\0';
   ```

   What you need is:

   ```
   nn=new node;
   nn->info=inf;
   nn->link = NULL;
   c->next = nn;
   c = nn;
   ```
5. You are modifying the global variables `p` and `c` in `display`. If you try to add any more items after the call to `display`, you will get unexpected behavior. Using local variables in `display` will prevent that problem.

   ```
   void display()
   {
       Node* n = f;
       while( n != NULL)
       {
           cout << n->info << " ";
           n = n->link;
       }
       cout << endl;
   }
   ```

**Suggested cleanup**

You don't need the variable `nn` in the global scope. It's used only in `create`. Remove it from the global scope and put it in `create`.

You don't need the global variable `p` at all. The only place you thought it would be useful is in the `else` block. But, as you can see, it is not needed there.

Use `NULL` instead of `'\0'` to compare pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
      p->link=nn;
```

You are adding new node in same position and not updating 'p'. So if you add 2 nodes, the second one is added where the first one was, and the first one is lost. Hence you always see only the last one added.